# If $a,b,c$ be three proportionals, show that $a:a+b=a-b:a-c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ be three proportionals, show that $a:a+b=a-b:a-c$

Given $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{c} \Rightarrow \dfrac{a}{a+b}=\dfrac{a-b}{a-c}. \ \ \ $ Also it can be noted $ac=b^2$.

$a(a-c)=(a+b)(a-b) \Rightarrow a^2-ac=a^2-b^2 \Rightarrow -ac=-b^2  \Rightarrow ac=b^2$

Is this the correct way to show this? Because I just took the end result and made a reverse calculation. Or am I supposed to take $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{c}$ and derive the end result from this only? Thanks.

Comment: You can reverse the 3rd line like this: $a(a-c)=(a+b)(a-b) \Leftrightarrow a^2-ac=a^2-b^2 \Leftrightarrow -ac=-b^2  \Leftrightarrow ac=b^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine since

$$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{c}\iff ac=b^2$$

and

$$\frac a{a+b}=\frac{a-b}{a-c} \iff a(a-c)=(a-b)(a+b) \iff a^2-ac=a^2-b^2 \iff ac=b^2$$

therefore the two expression are equivalent *with the conditions* $b\neq 0$, $c\neq 0$, $a\neq -b$, $a\neq c$.

Note that they are not completely equivalent since the first one holds also for $a=c\neq 0$ and $a\neq -b\neq 0$.

Comment: I only understand $b\neq0, c\neq0$ because they are in the denominator. The other conditions I don't understand. In particular $a\neq -b$. Can you please them to me? Thank you.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718349/if-a-b-c-be-three-proportionals-show-that-aab-a-ba-c#comment9994279_4718353), also $a + b$, which is $0$ if $a = -b$, and $a - c$, which is $0$ if $a = c$, are in the denominator.

Comment: We have two identity, the first one $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{c}$ is defined for $bc\neq 0$, the second one is $\frac a{a+b}=\frac{a-b}{a-c}$ which is well defined also for $bc=0$ when $a+b\neq 0$ and $a-c\neq 0$. For that reason the two identities are not completely equivalent without any other specification.

Answer (score 1):

By *fraction arithmetic*, recall that if

$$\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{b}{c}$$

with $\thinspace a≠-b\wedge a≠c\thinspace $ or $\thinspace b≠-c\wedge a≠c\thinspace $, then :

$$
\begin{align}\overbrace{\underbrace{\dfrac{a}{a+b}=\dfrac{b}{b+c}}_{\color{#c00}{(a+b)-(b+c)}}}^{\color{#0a0}{a-b}}=\dfrac {a-b}{a-c}\end{align}
$$

which completes the solution .

---

$\color{#c00}{\rm \bf{Fraction \thinspace \thinspace arithmetic }}$

If $\thinspace \dfrac AB=\dfrac CD\thinspace $ with $\thinspace A≠-B\thinspace $ or $\thinspace C≠-D\thinspace $, then :

$$\frac{A}{A+B}=\frac {C}{C+D}$$

and if $\thinspace\dfrac AB=\dfrac CD\thinspace$ with $\thinspace B≠D\thinspace$, then :

$$\frac AB=\frac CD=\frac {A-C}{B-D}\thinspace .$$